# Getting specific table row based on id mysql DB

Tags: php

I have a database where I view all the records, the last column is the table ID, I click it and I want to be able to edit that rows data only, here's what I got but it doesn't waork after updating phpmyadmin:::

```
      <?php

include "db.inc.php";

$id=$_GET['id'];

      $order = "SELECT * FROM ircb where id='$id'";
      $result = mysql_query($order);
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      ?>
      <form method="post" action="update.php">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo "$row[id]"?>">

        <tr>        
          <td>Date</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="cdate" 
         value="<? echo "$row[cdate]"?>" size="30"  style="color: black;background-color:#FFFF11">
          </td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>        
          <td>Item</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="item" 
         value="<? echo "$row[item]"?>" size="30"  style="color: black;background-color:#FFFF11">
          </td>
        </tr>
```

I end up getting no results returned, when I hover over the link it does display the correct table row id but when I click the link I get empty boxes containing some of the code like `<? echo` in the fields..no true values though..and the page header after clicking the link does show  ::: ...../edit_form.php?id=8  for row 8 so I assume something in my query is not quite right.
thanks

Comment: just to clear up my meaning a bit..Table is displayed, I do have the last column, table id's as a clickable link which when clicked should just return all of the data in that row, display the data and allow me to update the data, I just can't seem to get it to display the data, wondering where my query is wrong.. thanks

Comment: print `mysql_error()`, to see if you had an error in the query or something else (for ex: there may be some error in db.inc.php)?

Comment: Nope, no error in db.inc..  I did an echo $id to check if variable was being passed and it seems not, so perhaps its in my initial code  :: which is FOR THE ID VARIABLE ::: <td><a href='edit_form.php?id=$rows[id]'></a></td>    Does something here seem wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you try to `GET` a name "id" from a form which is `POST`ed ;) And also embed PHP in html more clearly. For example, `value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"` is more "true" rather than `value="<? echo "$row[id]"?>"` ;)