# mysql Database, click link to edit table row values

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting specific table row based on id mysql DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843809/getting-specific-table-row-based-on-id-mysql-db)

I have a database that is displayed but I want to have the table "id" become a link to edit that table row.  So if I display 10 rows of data the last column will be the row's id's and clicking the id is a link to an edit form for that particular row.
What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Use a plugin. google it.

Comment: How is this question different from your last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843809/getting-specific-table-row-based-on-id-mysql-db?

Comment: I guess you want phpMyAdmin :)

Comment: it's not different...I guess I am not sure where to start, trying to ask from a different angle, start fresh because obviously gooing from phpmyadmin 3 to 5 there are things that have changed.  Sorry for asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without knowing in what context you have this requriment..

on the page that lists your records, chuck them in an HTML table
for the collumn that holds the ID, render that out as

```
<php echo '<a href="edit.php?id='.ResultsArray[ID].'">Edit</a>'; ?>
```

then in your edit page (edit.php)
use the id passed in via the URL e.g $_GET['id']..to list a form that will allow you to edit that record

your SQL will use the WHERE clase to filter to the recod that was selected

Comment: on results page I have::: <a href='edit_form.php?id=$rows[id]'>  but obvioulsy not working, on the edit page I have :::$id=$_GET['id'];  thanks will try first suggestion... also sorry, not sure how to properly put "code" in correct format in reply box, ctrl K doesnt seem to work .

Comment: the :: <a href="edit.php?id='.ResultsArray[ID].'">  gives me a "page cannot be found" message